# Where is the VirtualBox installation folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, software-installation, directory

The Oracle VM VirtualBox® User Manual states that VirtualBox is installed into `/opt/VirtualBox/`, but it is not at that location.  I tried

```
$ cd /
$ sudo ls -lR | grep "VirtualBox"
```

and also searched for `vbox` without any luck on either.  A search on AskUbuntu just returned a heap of hits on folders shared between the guest and host.

Really, I am just after the Windows 7 guest additions `.iso` file as you can't download it separately from the Oracle site anymore.  Also, how do you install the extensions?

Regards,
Hedley

Comment: The guest additions iso is in `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`(if you installed the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package).

Answer (score 11):

The guest additions iso is in `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`
(if you installed the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package).

**How do I know this?**

This command:

```
dpkg -L virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

lists all the files that the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package installs and where they are located.
You can do this for any package you have installed.

You can also use the *Synaptic Package Manager* to get this information graphically.

**To install the guest additions:**

Just boot the virtual machine, and when it gets to the desktop open the **Devices** menu, click **Install Guest Additions CD Image...** and follow the instructions.

Comment: So far for `VirtualBox` **6.1.40** the directory is still the same - `/usr/share/virtualbox/` - it even if was installed through `sudo dpkg -i XXX.deb`

Comment: VirtualBox always failed to download Guest Additions and it turns out I just needed to install this (`virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`) package.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: You can get the VboxGuestAdditions_?.?.?.iso from http://downloads.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/