# How to export and import VirtualBox VM images?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

In VirtualBox you can create VM and it will store it on a folder inside the *Default Machine Folder* of VirtualBox.

For instance, after create an `ubuntu-headless` VM it will create an `ubuntu-headless` directory with a couple of files and more folders inside.

I want to get this VM working on another system with also VirtualBox, like a duplicate.

Will a simple copy/paste of this VM directory inside *Default Machine Folder* of the target system work?

TL;DR: How to transfer a VirtualBox image from one system to another?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Copy/pasting the VM files is not the way to go. You need to use the correct export/import feature of VirtualBox.

With the following instructions you will be able to transfer a VM across several different physical machines and it's also a good way to make backups.

### Export

Open VirtualBox and enter into the `File` option to choice `Export Appliance...`

[image: at the top left corner, then file and export appliance]

You will then get an assistance window to help you generate the image.

1. Select the VM to export
2. Enter the output file path and name

   [image: be careful with the output path and file name making sure to leave the file extension untouched]

   You can choice a format, which I always leave the default OVF 1.
3. Finally you can write metadata like Version and Description

Now you have an OVA file that you can carry to whatever machine to use it.

### Import

Open VirtualBox and enter into the `File` option to choice `Import`

You will then get an assistance window to help you loading the image.

1. Enter the path to the file that you have previously exported

   [image: chose the previously generated file]
2. Then you can modify the settings of the VM like RAM size, CPU, etc.

   [image: give a configuration according to your system, not all of it but enough]

   My recommendation on this is to enable the *Reinitialize the MAC address of all the network cards* option
3. Press `Import` and done!

Now you have cloned the VM from the host machine into another one

Comment: The only downside is that I would lose snapshots in the process, and indeed I would miss it in many situations.

Comment: This answer would be perfect if there was an answer to "Will a simple copy/paste of this VM directory inside Default Machine Folder of the target system work?".

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Imported machine never starts.

Comment: I just tried this and it works. The virtual machine has to be off when  you doing export. Here's an article that this is a right way to do this in 2017. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-export-virtualbox-virtual-machines-as-appliances/

Answer (score 40):

Here's the procedure for exporting a virtualbox VM via the command line:

First, use `vboxmanage list vms` to determine which box you want to export, e.g.

```
$ vboxmanage list vms
"vpn-client" {99378e99-d5c4-4bea-87ab-ca5ab28febea}
"vpn-client_1" {409eaa40-59c2-4259-9188-eef7479f1b91}
"kohadevbox_default_1430411165168_43224" {e9aa10d9-8aa3-4186-a39b-014b2c3589dc}
"kohadevbox_default_1431032598419_15901" {f384ba7e-d842-421e-b194-70a9573479eb}
"bc-koha-git" {76ad3f69-4acb-4332-b4a2-bf929a281f8f}
"nekls-git-29295" {68bb8720-e12b-49b9-a137-65bff75be66d}
"bc-kohaclone-git" {8b049d97-ff3b-4799-87e0-bda26f822ae0}
"bc-anthrolit-git" {dc435bbe-ded0-4cb2-baf3-4e7c6532fdf8}
"bc-maplleaf-git" {5a6c1e94-766f-4f93-96dc-8da07b0addd8}
"bc-mapleleaf2-git" {4aee2010-c834-4acc-971d-606ec950c938}
"Ubuntu VPN Client" {a0cf4d62-94ad-4d2e-ae0d-2bd2fc2765ae}
"kohadevbox_jessie_1449028830412_79167" {57ab8e8c-4e1a-452c-b324-cd0ae84374ba}
"kohadevbox_wheezy_1449030179528_35330" {ec8e3493-543d-424c-bf51-3ac5601a26ff}
"kohadevbox2_jessie_1463457128498_11997" {00f0d140-7c77-42f8-8512-92e4dded9c37}
```

In this case, I'm going to export `vpn-client_1`

```
$ vboxmanage export vpn-client_1 -o vpn-client_1.ova                                                                  
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

To import, use

```
vboxmanage import vpn-client_1.ova
```

The `-n` option will prompt you for import options; see `vboxmanage --help` for details.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, there's also a command line utility called [`VBoxManage`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf).  It'll likely reside in your [`/usr/share/virtualbox/`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540526/where-is-the-virtualbox-installation-folder-on-ubuntu) folder.  Use [`VBoxManager export`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export) and [`VBoxManager import`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-import).