# How do I copy the VM to another computer?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to copy my virtual machine to another computer and use it as nothing's changed in the second pc (anything such as history, snapshot, uuid, etc.) I use in both computers Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Just copy and paste the directory containing everything for the VM into the other computer.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **EXPORT** your VM from source machine and **IMPORT** it back on destination machine.

Check this link:
[How to export and import VirtualBox VM images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588426/how-to-export-and-import-virtualbox-vm-images)