# Can I backup a system and load it to a Virtual Machine?

Tags: server, partitioning, virtualbox, backup, virtualization

I would like to ask if someone has backup a live system to an image and later load this image to a virtual machine. If so it would be great to provide us some information about the procedure and the configuration needs to be made.

After some reading I believe that a working solution might be the following  procedure :

1. Create a virtual System image using a tool like [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/) .
2. Convert the image file to a more suitable format like .ova etc
3. Load the formatted file to a virtual machine using [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Thanks in regard .

Related Articles

[What is the best way to clone the system and backup files in Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086205/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-the-system-and-backup-files-in-ubuntu-18-10)

[How to export and import VirtualBox VM images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588426/how-to-export-and-import-virtualbox-vm-images)

*[Migrate from a virtual machine (VM) to a physical system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system)*

Comment: Search the interwebs for P2V to get some ideas... for me that yields a link from CloneZilla even: https://clonezilla.org/lecture-materials/016_Linux_Tag_2014_workshop/workshop/P2V-by-Clonezilla.pdf

Comment: You can absolutely clone a system and then load it into a virtualbox machine, I have done it. I am not sure what you mean by a "live system" though; that usually means a system booted off USB and I don't know about that. I cloned my system, then booted virtualbox into Clonezilla and read in the copy. I copied just the system partition (/), not the separate /home partition (this was basically an experiment). I had set the virtualbox partitions up first.